# Backup and Restore in a HyperVM instance to a network share

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-backup, homegroup

I have an up-to-date Windows 10 HyperV instance stored on my SSD drive (C:), and I would like to use the 'Backup and Recovery' feature to store an image of the VM on my HDD (D:).

Right-clicking on my D: drive on the host machine:

```
Properties > Sharing > Advanced Sharing > [X] Share this folder (select this box)
```

It is now accessible over the network, and I can add it to my HyperV VM by right-clicking in the File Explorer (in the VM) under 'This PC' and selecting 'Add a network location' and entering `\\myHostMachine\D`.

In the `Backup and Restore` applet (in the VM), click `Set up backup` which will display this window:

[image: set up backup]

Select `Save on a network` to get the `Select a network location` prompt:

[image: select a network location]

In the `Network Location` box I enter `\\myHostMachine\D`, which I have verified is working above. I can even select it using the `Browse` prompt under the `Network` directory. I enter my Microsoft account credentials (used on the host machine), which I know works because I also use them when I connect through Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Upon clicking `Okay`, it attempts to set up and then displays the `specified network location cannot be used` error (0x80070544):

[image: specified network location cannot be used]

I tried creating a VHD on my D: drive and sharing+backing up to there, but that also did not work. Is this not a supported use case, or am I messing something up in my setup?